# How to make width of datagrid autofit to parent control width

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Having a DataGrid inside a grid, I would like to make the datagrid width and datagrid columns auto fit inside the parent control.

So that if user decide to increase window width, how do I make the grid width and its columns also increase?

```
<Window x:Class="AME.WpfBidouille.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>           
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Publication date"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="A very large field to be displayed"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Omega" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Crée le" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Login" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Demandeur" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you can try adding `ColumnWidth="*"` to the DataGrid

Comment: Remove your hardset `Width="525"`

Comment: @Chris & @ Darius : Does not help. columns width remains the same size.

Comment: try setting `Width="*"` on all the columns

Comment: sure.. let me add this as answer so to help others too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Width` on each of your columns to `"*"`

```
    <DataGrid>           
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Publication date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="A very large field to be displayed"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="N° Omega" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Crée le" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Login" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Demandeur" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Type" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Status" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could do this is to create a Style and use that to apply it to the `DataGrid`

```
    <Style x:Key="DynamicGridColumns" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*" />
    </Style>

    <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DynamicGridColumns}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Publication date"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A very large field to be displayed"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Omega" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Crée le" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Login" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Demandeur" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```